# User name is not displayed

Tags: php

I'm trying to display username (cocname), but nothing happened. Do you see why? there is no error but the username is missing also and "Hello" is not displayed.Thank you.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';
$prepend = "<span class='cocname'>";
$append = "</span>";
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
header("Location: signin.php");
}
$query = "SELECT cocname FROM users WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email'];
$result = $connect->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $prepend."Hello ".$row['cocname'].$append;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide some more code. Like what happens when a user is successfully logged in

Comment: Where should the user go after entering a correct combination of username and password.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: No because i've not time last two days. I hope today.

Comment: @Paspartu Did the Update 2 worked

Comment: No, maybe problem is not there. I dont know where a'm wrong

Comment: My last try, UPDATE 3

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to use `sessions` here. For all the pages where you need login to work. Add this statement.

```
session_start();
```

Now, add `session_start();` as the first line of your login page. Update your login page as below.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
//user logged in
$_SESSION['logged'] =1;
$_SESSION['email']=$user;
//now since this would only return 1 result, you don't need to use a white loop.
 $user_details = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Read more :- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: did you mean in main page or in login page?

Comment: Where you want the user login to work, you need to have `session_start()`. Read more about sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Do write this in signing.php

```
$query = "SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email ='$user' and 
password='$pass'" ;  
$result = $connect->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
   header('Location: signin.php?failed=1');
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Email and password matched
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['User'] = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

And in main.php check if user is logged in or not as

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in']){
   echo "Successfully logged in";
}else{
   echo "Login first to view this page";
}
```

Don't forget to start session on the top of page. And use $_SESSION["User"] to show user info on main page.

**Update :**
You should submit your form on the "signin.php" itself. If the user is successfully logged in, save a session like `$_SESSION["is_login"] = true;` and another session containing user info and redirect to the main.php. In the main.php check if "is_login" session is set and is true. If true user is logged in and show there user info from info session. If "is_login" session is not set redirect the user to "signin.php" to signin again.

**Update 2**

The only solution i found for you is
replace

```
$query = "SELECT cocname FROM users WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email'];
```

with

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$query = "SELECT cocname FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
```

**Update 3**
Replace
    `$query = "SELECT cocname FROM users WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email'];`
With
    `$query = "SELECT cocname FROM users WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'";`

Comment: it's say ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: provide the code in    main.php. Also i have edited the answer

Comment: I will be happy if you show me where and what i need to change or remove or add, becouse i'm new in programming. thank you.

Comment: I cannot make you learn programming step by step here. I am giving you instruction here how the flow should be. Implement it by your own if the problem persist i m here to solve that also

Comment: @Paspartu Did you get your solution ?

Comment: @Paspartu Did you followed the given instructons

Comment: that i'm tryng now :) so i sed i'm new

Comment: I'm change the question, can you see? Thanks